# Woocommerce login not working on the first try

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, login, wp-login-form

Sometimes the woocommerce login form is not working on the first try, but it is working on the second one. There are no error messages, the POST contains all the necessary information, and I made sure that the submitted information is correct, yet the page gets reloaded without logging in the user (no error in the logs). On the second try, it works perfectly.

I have tried debugging it, by following the user login process, that can be found [here](https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-login-hooks/). Unfortunately I am having a very hard time with this simple issue. I have inserted a `die()`, in the `wp_authenticate` action, but on the first try, it seems that this action isn't even called.

What should I check to find the problem?

Comment: I have found the problem, in the woocommerce plugin, there is a function called "process_login()" , and in that function:  `wp_verify_nonce( $nonce_value, 'woocommerce-login' )` returns **false** on the first try... One step closer to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. If you are having a strange validation problem that ONLY happens when you first load a page, and you have Woocommerce running on this particular site it might help you too.

Solution to my specific problem:

```
 /**
 * WooCommerce login not working on first try fix
 */
add_filter('nonce_user_logged_out', function($uid, $action) {
  if ($uid && $uid != 0 && $action && $action == 'woocommerce-login') {
     $uid = 0;
  }
   return $uid;
}, 100, 2);
```

More info about this issue [here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/38515765-woocommerce-when-user-is-not-logged-in-but-items-in-carts-messes-with-our-nonce-validation) and [here](https://www.sprisemedia.com/blog/wp-nonce-validation-fails/).

Comment: thank you for sharing the snippet, it works.

Comment: Glad it helped! The StackExchange way of thanking someone by the way is to upvote their answer, though I realise you don't have enough points here to do that just yet.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/260922)